# Apply FadeIn effect to WebView

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a WebView that I want to fade in after loading the page, I've tested fading out/in other elements but this is not working with control. Is there any way to get this visual effect to work with WebView?

Comment: Are you loading your own web content or someone else's? If your own, you could apply a fade-in effect on the content itself.

Comment: Someone else's, a site to be precise, either way, how would it be possible to do it if the content was mine? Fade in using JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebView is implemented in a different way from most of the other elements.  It is drawn in its own window even though it is mixed with your other XAML elements.

That' means that you cant' do certain thing with WebView

- No transparency (which means no fading either).
- Can't overlay another element over the Webvew
  -

Comment: I was aware of the "own window on top of all" but didn't knew about it ignoring the opacity altogether. Anyway, is there a feasible way to do it by injecting javascript in the WebView ? (I'm loading a website)

Comment: Do you want the webview to fade or some of the items showm in the webview to fade?

Comment: I want my loading screen to fade to the WebView page, doesn't really matter if it's the WebView control fading in or a WebView with a similar background to my loading screen and the elements of the webpage fading in. Hence, if there is someway to easily have all of the website elements fading in, maybe the trick can be pulled off without having to change the site itself.

EDIT

That being said, maybe I can render the website to a brush, fade in the brush and exchange the brush to the WebView without being too noticing, need to try it.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as it's true but, for the record, this can in fact be implemented with some javascript magic. One may argue that it is too much work for the result, it is, but at least it can be done.

On another note, with the improvements made to WebView in Windows 8.1, don't know if this issue still persists.